# How do I scan for part of a character?

Tags: bash, shell, utf-8, utf8mb4

I’m using bash shell with Mac El Capitan.  How can I scan for part of an 8-byte character in a series of files?  I got an error when building a project that read

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF3\x95\x90\x8D\xEA\x93...' for column 'CODE' at row 1
```

and I’d like to figure out where this string value is coming into play.  Unfortunately the error does not give me more information but I know the directory of all the potential files where this could live.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrupted one of my shell files on purpose in the current directory, inserting a `0xf3` char using an hex editor.

I've written this (clumsy) script which uses `od` (octal dump) in hex mode char-by-char, with hex offset, and greps for the infamous `f3` char in the current directory and in all directories below, filtering on files and name (so you can remove the name filtering it still works)

```
find . -type f -name "*.sh" | while read f
do
    line=$(od -Ax -t x1 $f | grep -w f3)
    if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
      echo file $f is corrupt: $line
    fi
done
```

result on my directory:

```
file ./quote.sh is corrupt: 000010 69 6d 61 6c f3 3d 24 28 6d 79 73 71 6c 20 2d 75
```

Comment: I don't know what file this character occurs in within my directory so I switched your line "for f in *.sh" to "for f in *" but get the error "od: src: read error: Is a directory" and "od: target: read error: Is a directory".